# Can an IPython/Jupyter notebook cell be imported as if it were a module?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a means in IPython to `import` the contents of a notebook cell as if it were a separate module? Or alternatively get the contents of a cell to have its own namespace.

Comment: Yes, check [Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html)

Comment: @armatita You should add this as an answer :)

Comment: @ChristianTernus Done. I put it in a comment because I actually never tried it before (I'm not a Jupyter user) but the document seems very complete. As so I wrote a more complete (meaning quoted stuff from the site) answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@Mike, as mentioned in the comment you can follow the well documented steps in the following link to import a Jupyter Notebook as a module:

[Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html)

In the link they will mention the work done in Python to provide users with [hooks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#id21) (now superseded with [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) and [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)) to provide better customization of the import mechanism.

As so the recipe they propose is the following:

> - load the notebook document into memory
> - create an empty Module
> - execute every cell in the Module namespace

, and they offer their own implementation for the [Notebook Loader](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Notebook-Loader) (unnecessary if the code is all pure python):

```
class NotebookLoader(object):
    """Module Loader for Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
        self.path = path

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        """import a notebook as a module"""
        path = find_notebook(fullname, self.path)

        print ("importing Jupyter notebook from %s" % path)

        # load the notebook object
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = read(f, 4)


        # create the module and add it to sys.modules
        # if name in sys.modules:
        #    return sys.modules[name]
        mod = types.ModuleType(fullname)
        mod.__file__ = path
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__dict__['get_ipython'] = get_ipython
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod

        # extra work to ensure that magics that would affect the user_ns
        # actually affect the notebook module's ns
        save_user_ns = self.shell.user_ns
        self.shell.user_ns = mod.__dict__

        try:
          for cell in nb.cells:
            if cell.cell_type == 'code':
                # transform the input to executable Python
                code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
                # run the code in themodule
                exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        finally:
            self.shell.user_ns = save_user_ns
        return mod
```

Also here is the implementation for the [Notebook Finder](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#The-Module-Finder):

```
class NotebookFinder(object):
    """Module finder that locates Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.loaders = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        nb_path = find_notebook(fullname, path)
        if not nb_path:
            return

        key = path
        if path:
            # lists aren't hashable
            key = os.path.sep.join(path)

        if key not in self.loaders:
            self.loaders[key] = NotebookLoader(path)
        return self.loaders[key]
```

And the final step being the [registration](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Register-the-hook) of the new module:

```
sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())
```

All of this is, however, a direct quote from the first link given in this answer. The document is well built and provides answers for other stuff such as [displaying notebooks](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Aside:-displaying-notebooks) or dealing with [packages](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html#Notebooks-in-packages).